How to toggle button color onclick vuetify v-btn?
I want to toggle the colors of the selection button onclick between 'black' and 'primary'
<template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-btn color="black" v-bind="props"> SELECTION </v-btn>
</template>

I'm facing syntax issue in binding color to v-bind. How can the toggling of colors be achieved?

What is the slot for? is it a vuetify component? can you provide more information?

You must use v-bind with the color prop to dynamically set it. Either v-bind:color="" or using shorthand :color="". Bind a variable, then with a click event handler, toggle the variable value between "black" and "primary"

<template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
    <v-btn :color="btnColor" @click="toggleColor" v-bind="props"> SELECTION </v-btn>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const btnColor = ref('black')

  function toggleColor() {
    if (btnColor.value === 'black') btnColor.value = 'primary'
    else btnColor.value = 'black'
  }
</script>

Vuetify Playground example

How to use v- bind if there is already props added to it? Like you can see in the code, I have already used props

v-bind is not limited to one use.  You can bind multiple properties.  Answer code has been updated.
